# Visual Studio 2013 - is there a way to re-structure the code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I've written some messy laid out code, is there a way in VS2013 to re-structure it with the click of a button?

Comment: Ctrl+A, Ctrl+X, Ctrl+V

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general the keystroke is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>. However, if you're in an Express version I believe it's <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>. But bear in mind this can really determine on how your environment is setup.

Comment: what do you mean by ED or KD ?

Comment: @MauricioGracia, hold down the control key and then press `E` and then `D`.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud maybe "CTRL + E + D" is more clear ?

Comment: Visual Studio displays multi-key keyboard shortcuts like "Ctrl +E, D".  That's a good convention to follow.

Comment: @Warren, thanks a lot friend; I've edited to follow that convention.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the file type, but **Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document** often knocks C# and VB.NET files into much better shape.  Keyboard shortcut is (usually) **Ctrl+E, D**.

Resharper, a popular (but not free) Visual Studio plugin, offers a ton of interesting code formatting features as well, whereby you can define all the rules by which code "should" be laid out, then you run one command and it'll clean everything up.  You can even save those settings in a configuration file inside the project, so that your whole team can share it.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + K + D (Entire document)

Ctrl + K + F (Selection only)

Comment: These are the defaults of the "General Development" settings.